# How to load extra libraries for GDB?

Tags: c++, emacs, cuda, gdb

I'm trying to debug a CUDA program, but when I'm launching `gdb` like so:

```
$ gdb -i=mi <program name>
$ r <program arguments>
```

I'm getting:

```
/home/wvxvw/Projects/cuda/exercise-1-udacity/cs344/HW2/hw: 
error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.5.0: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Process gdb-inferior killed
```

*(formatted for readability)*

(I'm running gdb using <kbd>M-x</kbd>`gdb`) If that matters, then CUDA libraries are in the `.bashrc`

```
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
```

Comment: If you want to debug a CUDA program are you intending to run `gdb` or `cuda-gdb` ?

Comment: I don't think it is the cause of your current issue with the cudart library, but if, down the road, you want to debug device code, you should use `cuda-gdb` instead.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.5.0

This error has nothing to do with GDB: your executable, when run from inside GDB, can't find the library it needs.

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64"

GDB runs your program in a new `$SHELL`, so that should have worked. I wonder if there is some interaction with emacs.

In any case, this:

```
(gdb) set env LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/lib64
(gdb) run
```

should fix this problem.

**Update**:

> as I've mentioned it before, ld path is set properly

No, it **isn't**. If it was, you wouldn't have the problem.

Now, I don't know *why* it isn't set properly. If you really want to find out, start by running GDB outside emacs (to exclude possible emacs interactions).

If the problem is still present, gdb `show env`, `shell env`, adding `echo "Here"` to your `~/.basrc`, etc. should help you find where things are not working as you expect them.

Comment: The `export` trick works on OS X with `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, too. `set env` did not work on OS X.

Answer (score 4):

I've had this problem as well. One way to look at it is that even if the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is correct when you enter `show env` into gdb, it may not be correct when you actually execute the program because gdb executes `$SHELL -c <program>` to run the program. Try this as a test, run `$SHELL` from the command line and then `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Is it correct? If not, then you probably need to add it to your rc (.tcshrc in my case).

Comment: This is a great tip. We've found great success with unsetting `$SHELL` prior to launch to avoid this problem. You can do this just for gdb by using `env` e.g. `$ env --unset=SHELL  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your/path gdb`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when trying to run gdb on windows 7. I use MobaXterm to access a Linux toolbox. I installed gdb separately from  http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/ . I got it to work by making sure gdb could find the correct .dll files as mentioned by Employed Russian. If you have MobaXterm installed the .dll files should appear in your home directory in MobaXterm/slash/bin.

gdb however did not recognize the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. For me, it worked when I used the PATH variable instead:

```
    (gdb) set env PATH C:\Users\Joshua\Documents\MobaXterm\slash\bin
    (gdb) run
```

I would think using `PATH` instead of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` might work for you provided you put the correct path to your library.

Comment: PATH variable worked for me and LD_LIBRARY_PATH didn't thanks.

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't append to the path, but it _replaces_ the path

Comment: The reason `PATH` worked in your case is given what you've posted, you are in Windows, no Linux/POSIX like the original poster. (Yes, I know this is a very old answer, but it has a couple upvotes and "worked for me" without context for _why_.  Windows is _why_.)

Answer (score 1):

gdb is looking for a library, so why are you concerned with the include path?  You may want to  try to set the gdb option "solib-search-path" to point to the location of the libcudart.so.5.0 library.

Comment: Just to get past the obvious.  Are you certain that the library you want is in that directory?  Are you certain that you are building a 64 bit application?  Are the permissions set correctly?  And I'm guessing you are able to run this when you don't use GDB?